# jQuery one-page website scrolling/hash problems

Tags: jquery, hash, scroll

I want to create a 1 page website with multiple (html5) sections that contain all the sub-pages. There is a fixed navigation. Here are a couple of requirements:

- When the navigation links are clicked (eg. #home, #about-me) I want it to smoothly scroll to the section
- I want to use hashes in the URL like domain.com/#about-me
- I want users to be able to use the back/forward buttons from their browsers, and when used it smoothly scrolls to that section
- When the URL domain.com/#about-me is loaded straight away, I want it to smoothly scroll to the #about-me section from the top.

I've been trying to figure this out for days. I tried doing this from scratch and with tons of different plugins like the BBQ plugin. I couldn't figure it out. But I learned a bit so I decided to start from scratch again. I prefer to write it myself without plugins because that's lightweight. However I have no problem with using a plugin at all if it's too much of a hassle to write it myself.

Right now I have this HTML, a simple navigation:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about-me">About me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and sections:

```
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <section id="home">
        <div>content...</div>
    </section>
    <section id="about-me">
        <div>content...</div>
    </section>
    etc...
</div>
```

Now for the jQuery part:

```
// Function to check if section exists
function isSection(section){
    if($('section'+section).length > 0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

// Scroll function
function scrollToSection(section){
    var offset = $(section).offset().top;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: offset
    }, 600);
}

// The Click() function
$('nav ul a').click(function(){
    var section = $(this).attr('href');
    if(isSection(section)){
        scrollToSection(section);
    }
})
```

Right away I come across a problem. The hash changes but it instantly jumps to the section, and a split second later it does the scrolling animation anyway (from it's previous starting position). I could use preventDefault() (which causes a perfect smooth animation) but than the hash doesn't change. It's nice that it changes the hash so the browser history works, but no scrolling happens when the history buttons are pressed.

How would I go from here keeping the top requirements in mind? Any recommendations and preferably examples?

I heard the [BBQ hashchange](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) plugin works pretty good for all this? How would I implement this? The documentation doesn't quite consider my requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You could use set location.hash manually to change the url once the animation is complete. First, you would use preventDefault to let it animate. After it scrolled to where you wanted to go you could use location.

```
// Scroll function
function scrollToSection(section){
    var offset = $(section).offset().top;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: offset
    }, 600, function(){
       window.location.hash = section;
    });
}

// The Click() function
$('nav ul a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var section = $(this).attr('href');
    if(isSection(section)){
        scrollToSection(section);
    }
    return false;
})​
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/p5L57/

Another approach is to let the links change the hashes as they normally do. But, we can use the onhashchange event to do our scrolling when the hash changes.

Replace your click handler with:

```
function locationHashChanged(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var section = location.hash;
    if(isSection(section)){
        scrollToSection(section);
    }
}

window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/XDWuS

This approach is better, but the way I used it in the jsfiddle hashes will not work outside of using the nav to go to sections. If you have other hashes on the page and you want scrolling to work for them too you can just remove the section specific code.

Also, it will only work in browsers that support the onhashchange event.http://caniuse.com/hashchange

Comment: Good suggestion. But this causes the same problem. It instantly jumps to the section, and a split second later it does the scrolling animation anyway.

Comment: @Bob I think I fixed that by only changing the hash once the animation completes.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the examples! I didn't do a return false, which I think caused the strange jumping problem. I thought preventDefault() would take care of that. But that part is covered! Thanks! Requirement 3 and 4 are still a mystery to me.

Comment: I added an alternative approach. That should get you #3 and 4

Comment: Hmmm your method for #3 and #4 doesn't work for me. Not in my website or the jsfiddle example. It acts like a normal hash link. [Here](http://bobmetz.nl/v1.php) is the actual site that i'm working on. The javascript is [here](http://bobmetz.nl/js/main.js). Am I misundestanding something?

Comment: I got a feeling we're almost there. I bet you know why this isn't working! @Adam

Comment: Ok, I made another change to use event.preventDefault in the hashchange function. Try that.